# Password generator output/ repetition

Tags: python, passwords, generator, shuffle

I've got two questions about the code included below. One I'm curious how do I prevent the code from putting the same number/symbol/letter(upper/lower) beside itself? for example  P@ssword I'd like to make it so it wont output (P@S$word, P@sSword, P@$$word).

Secondly I'm hoping someone can help confirm what/why the output for the code is . . .
#uI7c
cbI#7u
cbl#7Iu
7Ilbn#cu
Icbnl#7nu
u7bclnnI#I
nlu#cnIU7Ib
7c#9unnlIIUb

I'm under the impression it has to do with lines(32,33,38). it appears to be showing me it shuffling in each letter/number/symbol up to the MAX_LEN

```py
import random
import array

#adjust based on length required
MAX_LEN = 12

DIGITS = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
SYMBOLS = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')']
LOWER = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
UPPER = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

#Combines the above list into an array
list_array = DIGITS + SYMBOLS + UPPER + LOWER

#randomly select atleast 1 character from each 
rand_digit = random.choice(DIGITS)
rand_symbol = random.choice(SYMBOLS)
rand_upper = random.choice(UPPER)
rand_lower = random.choice(LOWER)

#combine Char randomly, only contains 4 char at this point in code
temp_pass = rand_digit + rand_symbol + rand_upper + rand_lower

#1 from each now fill the rest of MAX_LEN by selecting randomly
for x in range(MAX_LEN - 4):
    temp_pass = temp_pass + random.choice(list_array)


    #convert temp password into array and shuffle to prevent
    #consistent patterns/ begining of PW is predictable

    temp_pass_list = array.array('u', temp_pass)
    random.shuffle(temp_pass_list)

    #traverse temp PW array and append char to form PW
    password = ""
    for x in temp_pass_list:
        password = password + x

    #print Password
    print(password)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do this is to build the password entirely out of unique characters. In that way you would never have two identical characters adjacent to each other

Comment: In general, do *not* do this. It reduces the total number of possible passwords. This often isn't a *big* difference, but worst case it can be significant - so it should be avoided as an antipattern.